# How do I convert a json data field into array of one item

Tags: apache-nifi, jolt

I have a JSON like this

```json
{
  "id": 23,
  "ip": "10.98.91.248"
}
```

and would like to convert the "ip" field to an array of one item like below

```json
{
  "id": 23,
  "ip": [ "10.98.91.248" ]
}
```

I have tried the UpdateRecord processor with JSONTreeReader and JSONRecordSetWriter with default setting and adding a property

```
\\ip = "["${field.value}"]"
```

This didn't work.

Is there a better way to do this, such as Jolt Transform ?

Answer (score 1):

A NiFi JoltTransformJSON processor with the following spec worked in this case:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "ip": "ip[0]"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: even replacing `"ip": "ip[0]"` with `"ip": "&[0]"` is possible in order to prevent writing the key twice.

Comment: Thanks Barbaros, I will try that.